# Finding if an element in column A is paired with more than one discrete element of column B in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

Sorry if this is obvious I am new to python. I am trying to check if an element from dataframe column A occurs in the same row as more than one discrete elements from dataframe column B.

So for example if I have 2 columns:

```
d = {'A': [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 5, 5, 5, 5], 'B': ['pen', 'pen', 'pen', 'pen', 'pen', 'rubber', 'rubber', 'ruler', 'rubber'}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

In this example, an element from column A is on the same row as more than one element from column B (5 is on the same row as both rubber and ruler). What I would like determine is which elements from column A occur on the same row as more than 1 element on column B, and the specific elements from column B.

Assuming there is a match as described above, I would like to return something like:

```
5 : ['rubber', 'ruler']
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Group elements of `B` by unique values in `A` and create a `set` for each group. Later, you can filter out groups that have only one item in the `set`.

```
ans = df.groupby("A").B.apply(set).to_dict()
{k: list(v) for k, v in ans.items() if len(v) > 1}
# {5: ['rubber', 'ruler']}
```